# Java Thread.yield() strange behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading

here is my code :

```
  class MyThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println("Child Thread");
            Thread.yield();
            
        }
    }
}
  public class TestYield {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread obj = new MyThread();
        obj.start();
        for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println("Main Thread");
        }
    }
}
```

So there is 2 thread we could say, The second thread is started by the main thread, which means from that point, both threads started their execution parallelly. lets think the main their executed first for the 3 times so the output will be like :

```
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
```

as soon as execution counter will switch to the second thread, **"Child Thread"** should must be printed out until this point our output is extended to be like :

```
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Child Thread
```

but in the original output "main thread" is completing its execution first
so my question is :-

**Why didn't the first sysout("child thread") execute before the Thread.yield() ?**
the output I'm getting is:

```
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
```

**Update:**
My Problem has been solved now
here is the key points which is got learned from the **@Stephen C** and
**@user15793316**

1. Starting a new thread actually takes a significant amount of time.
   It could be milliseconds.
2. main thread is so fast that the child thread did not have been
   started (or finish being started) - maybe a yield in main would
   eventually help the child thread to get a chance to run. (and
   increasing from 10 to 100or more iterations)

So I updated my code and added line  `Thread.sleep((long) 0.1);`
Here is my updated code:

```
public class TestYield {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyThread obj = new MyThread();
        obj.start();
        Thread.sleep((long) 0.1);
        for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println("Main Thread");
        }
    }
}
```

what does is do is ? its put main thread in sleep for the very sort amount of time , so because of this, jvm can get some time to create a new thread.
I'm getting my expected output now

```
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Child Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Main Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
Child Thread
```

**P.S:** *now its very strange for me how I'm  getting the  exact output which i wanted to, supposed to be. main thread is executing first 3 time only (: lol!*

Comment: I believe that your expectations rely on a misunderstanding. The scheduler can execute and interleave or not in any order at its discretion. There is nothing in the documentation saying that you could not have the output that you observed.

Comment: thanks buddy, but I'm getting exact output which  i wanted to, supposed to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - main thread is so fast that the child thread did not have been started (or finish being started) - maybe a `yield` in main would eventually help the child thread to get a chance to run. (and increasing from `10` to `100`or more iterations)

2 - `yield` does not guarantee that another thread will run (from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()): *"The scheduler is free to ignore this hint."*) <sub>Not so relevant since there is no `yield` in main</sub>

3 - check the [java.util.concurrent.locks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) package. 
<sup>actually the `yield` documentation also states *"It is rarely appropriate to use this method."*</sup>

Comment: actually your first point is saved my life, I'm getting now what i was expecting, please see the changes in my question, and please correct me, if have made a mistake again

Answer (score 1):

OK, so let's start with the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()) for `yield()`.

> "A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. **The scheduler is free to ignore this hint.**
>
> Yield is a heuristic attempt to improve relative progression between threads that would otherwise over-utilise a CPU. Its use should be combined with detailed profiling and benchmarking to ensure that it actually has the desired effect.
>
> **It is rarely appropriate to use this method.** [...]"

Nowhere does this say that `yield()` has a predictable effect on scheduling.  So your expectations of predictable behavior are not well-founded.

---

As to what actually in happening in your example, it would appear that the `main` thread is completing its loop before the child thread's `run()` method is called.

Why?  Well it could be a couple of things:

1. Starting a new thread actually takes a significant amount of time.  It could be milliseconds.
2. Depending on things like the number of cores available, system load, native scheduler policy and so on, it could take some time for the thread scheduler to schedule a new thread to a physical core for execution.

For what it is worth, `yield()` appears NOT to be implicated in this ... since the output shows the last `println` in the main thread happening before the first one in the child thread.  The first `yield()` call is happening *too late* to have any effect on the output.

---

Finally, as the javadoc says: "It is rarely appropriate to use this method.".  So trying to figure out how it works *by experimentation* is probably a waste of your time.

Comment: Thankyou because of you, my problem has been solved now